# php remove specified characters in a given string using "preg_replace()"

Tags: php, preg-replace

How to remove the specific characters in a string(strip the "http://www." from a string)

For example, my string is like this: http://www.hooeeywebprint.com

Comment: How to read a [manual](http://www.php.net/preg_replace), although I'd use [str_replace](http://www.php.net/str_replace) here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one

```
var_dump(preg_replace("/^[^\.]*\.(.*)/", "\\1", "http://www.example.com"));
```

which removes everything from string up to first `.` character, including it.